# Can .DOC and .XLS files be converted to PDF on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, pdf

How can I convert .DOC and .XLS files to PDF?

Comment: Dude, you have a long way to go to get your questions answered. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I suppose the "iphone" tag is supposed to lead us to believe that you want to do this from an iPhone application?

Comment: sorry, i had not specified that, how to do this with ios programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a detour. If you can copy the files to your PC from iphone, use PrimoPDF. It installs as a printer in your system (Windows Platform) and gives the output file as PDF.

Whatever be the type of document, it will get converted to PDF if it can be printed.

Then re-transfer the files to your iphone.

Best of Luck!!

Comment: +1. But if this is the expected answer, the OP should have gone to superuser.com instead. This question has nothing to do with stackoverflow.com!!

Comment: Wow. Yeah, I guess. But then, you could also print the files out and scan them back in as a PDF.